# Omit % for some factor levels on tbl_summary and exclude them in tests

Tags: r, gtsummary

For some table like the example below

```
example <- data.table(
              sex = rep(c("Female","Male"),6),
              income = rep(c("[0,100[","Not applicable","[200,300[","[200,300[","I rather not to answer","[300,400["),2)
           )

example %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = sex) %>%
  add_p
```

[image]

is possible to not consider the `n` from `"Not applicable"` / `"I rather not to answer"` for the percentages and test?

I would like to get the following output:
[image]

where the p-value is from the test

```
fisher.test(example[!income %in% c("Not applicable","I rather not to answer")]$sex,
            example[!income %in% c("Not applicable","I rather not to answer")]$income)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.2'

example <- 
  data.frame(
    sex = rep(c("Female","Male"),6),
    income = rep(c("[0,100[","Not applicable","[200,300[","[200,300[","I rather not to answer","[300,400["),2)
  ) |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    not_applicable = income %in% "Not applicable",
    rather_not_say = income %in% "I rather not to answer",
    income = ifelse(not_applicable | rather_not_say, NA, income)
  )

example |>  
  tbl_summary(
    by = sex,
    statistic = c("not_applicable", "rather_not_say") ~ "{n}",
    missing = "no"
  ) |> 
  add_p(include = income) |> 
  modify_table_styling(
    columns = label, 
    rows = variable %in% c("not_applicable", "rather_not_say"),
    text_format = "indent"
  ) |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on SO
```

| **Characteristic** | **Female**, N = 6 | **Male**, N = 6 | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| income |  |  | 0.2 |
| [0,100[ | 2 (50%) | 0 (0%) |  |
| [200,300[ | 2 (50%) | 2 (50%) |  |
| [300,400[ | 0 (0%) | 2 (50%) |  |
| not_applicable | 0 | 2 |  |
| rather_not_say | 2 | 0 |  |

<sup>Created on 2024-02-12 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>